# Date value while debugging

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, delve

I am using VS Code, and while debugging if I check value of a time.Time variable/field, I get numeric value in "ext" of time.Time{} object.  What would be best way to evaluate it in human readable format (something like "2020-05-09T05:00:00Z")?  I tried `tm.String()` in watch section of debugger but get `Unable to eval expression: "function calls not allowed without using 'call'"`

Comment: How do all normally evaluate date field value while debugging?  I can add something like dtStr = dt.String() but I will have restart the debugger every time after adding the code.  Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

After just running into the same issue I've found out the debugger can indeed evaluate it by using 'call' as the error message states.

So instead of adding a watch in Visual Studio Code like this:

> tm.String()

Add a watch like this:

> call tm.String()

With that one call, you will get something like this in the watch window:
"2020-05-09 05:00:00 +0000 UTC"